# Diagnosing node crush in JMS communication through ActiveMQ

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have java applications (nodes) that communicate via JMS (ActiveMQ + Camel). I have situation like this one:

1.) Node_1 put message in queue
2.) message is in queue for a while, because Node_2 is busy
3.) Node_2 take message whenever is ready

Each node and ActiveMQ are in separable machines. Let's say that Node_2 became inaccessible (maybe machine just crushed). **What is the best way to inform Node_1 that Node_2 is inaccessible?**

I'm not jet fully familiar with those technologies. I have noticed that there is some kind of inactivity monitor, and I thought that it could be a good tool to use. Unfortunately, I do not know and can't find if I can use it to run a custom action in ActiveMQ side. **Can I run a custom action in ActiveMQ if Node_2 is inaccessible?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost: The idea of messaging and MOM is that you should not need to know if the other side has crashed or not since the messages will be delivered by ActiveMQ once the system has been fixed.

That said, the best thing you can do is to subscribe to message from `ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Queue.<YOUR QUEUE>` or `ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Queue.>` if you have a lot of queues. Doing so and you will be able to see (from node1) that node2 has stopped (or restarted) to consume messages which indicate a crash or similar.

read more here http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html

Comment: I will test it out. I know that messages will be delivered by ActiveMQ once the system has been fixed, but the truth is that my system is much more complicated and I need to know it for load balance reasons.

Comment: So it may be. But advisory messages is the way ActiveMQ react on different events in the system - so that's the way to go. Extending ActiveMQ with logic/java/camel routes to do other things is not that hard either, if you need more complex things